# More ticks on x-axis in a semilogx Python plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I would like to have more ticks on the x-axis of this plot (for example a tick for 20hz, 40hz, 80hz, 160hz, 320hz, 640hz, etc.):

[image]

Do you have an idea of how to adapt this code : ?

```
from numpy import cos, sin, pi, absolute, arange, log10, linspace
from pylab import figure, clf, plot, xlabel, ylabel, xlim, ylim, title, grid, axes, show, semilogx

f=linspace(20,20000, num=100)
ampl=linspace(-5,1, num=100)

semilogx(f, ampl, linewidth=2)
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Gain (dB)')
title('Frequency Response')
xlim(20, 20000)
ylim(-150, 10)
grid(True)
show()
```

PS : Here is the solution, thanks to the given answer :

```
t=[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024]` 
t1= [x*20 for x in t]
xticks(t1,t1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try [xticks()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks), I think this is what you need.

Comment: I'm not sure if my issue is with matplotlib's default behavior, this answer, or the lack of clarity in the docs but I find this answer unhelpful. If I zoom on a linear plot using `xlim` I get more ticks, if I do this on a semilog/log plot, I do not. I guess an example would make the answer better, but probably better defaults in matplotlib is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A note for anyone who comes across this - 
Be sure to call semilogx() *before* xticks(), otherwise your labels will be reset